# Angular Ui-Grid: Highlight entire row with pinned column

Tags: css, angularjs, ui-grid

I'm using ui-grid and the first column have to be pinned on the left. When the user hovers on one row, I want to highlight the entire row, which is the logical thing to do.

The problem is that ui-grid creates two distinct elements, one for the pinned column and the other on for the "regular" ones. So I don't know how to highlight the entire row at once, and solutions with CSS don't work.

```
.ui-grid-row:hover .ui-grid-cell {
  background-color: red;
}
```

Plunker here: http://plnkr.co/edit/HPxrc68JNMqyp4G9xLFA?p=preview.

Do you know how to do that ? Ideally just with ui-grid settings and CSS.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it!
I used a row template that grabs the row id, defines `ng-mouseover` and `ng-mouseout` functions that fills the background for all the cells in the row. For whatever reason I had to wrap the entire template in a `div`, simply adding something to the `class` of the template broke the entire table.

Content of the `rowTemplate`:

```
<div class="row-uid-{{row.uid}}">
    <div ng-repeat="(colRenderIndex, col) in colContainer.renderedColumns track by col.uid"
         ng-mouseover="grid.appScope.onRowHover(row.uid);"
         ng-mouseout="grid.appScope.onRowOut(row.uid);"
         ui-grid-one-bind-id-grid="rowRenderIndex + '-' + col.uid + '-cell'"
         class="ui-grid-cell"
         ng-class="{ 'ui-grid-row-header-cell': col.isRowHeader}"
         role="{{col.isRowHeader ? 'rowheader' : 'gridcell'}}"
         ui-grid-cell>
    </div>
</div>
```

Added functions in the controller:

```
 $scope.onRowHover = function (rowUid) {
    _.each(angular.element('.row-uid-' + rowUid + ' .ui-grid-cell-contents'), function (row) {
           angular.element(row).css('background-color', 'red');
    });
};

$scope.onRowOut = function (rowUid) {
    _.each(angular.element('.row-uid-' + rowUid + ' .ui-grid-cell-contents'), function (row) {
      angular.element(row).css('background-color', 'white');
    });
};
```